# Why can VSC not access my PC folders through local?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

I'm fairly new to VSC. However it seems when I open a new folder to access local files, it can only access old files on my PC. For example, I'm trying to access a downloaded file from udemy but it doesn't show up through VSC local. Very frustrating.

Comment: Not sure you're understanding project explorer to that of a file explorer. Try again.

Comment: I dont know what you mean. I followed the Udemy course, >open folder>show local> that's when VSC will not access recent downloaded files.

Comment: That's a pretty abstract abstract question. You should be more specific and provide more content for us to help you. Some screenshots, maybe.